# CSS - gap in footer

Tags: css, footer

gap in between browser window and footer
[image]

```
 #footer
 {
 text-align:center;
clear:both;
background: url("images/footer.png") repeat-x #8DC63F;
width:100%;
margin:0;
}


.footer-text 
{
padding: 10px 0 0;
white-space:nowrap;
font-family:'Tahoma';
font-size:10pt;
color: #000000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
<p class="footer-text">Home | Services | About Us | Products | Contact Us</p> 
<p class="footer-text">2011 &copy; All Rights Reserved.</p>
<p class="footer-text">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Help me to remove the extra space between browser window and footer

Comment: Can you paste your HTML code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using overflow:hidden in #footer.

Also, It would be great if you give us a URL that shows the gap. The problem is that sometimes CSS rules can affect multiple elements, so it's hard to tell what's going on exactly without the entire code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I re-checked my html css, switched back to the previous version I had. problem is solved.

Comment: This worked for me but I am very puzzled as to why `overflow:hidden` removes the extraneous white-space.

Comment: I don't know tecnically why this happens, but when you see unusual space in your page, moreover if you are using floats, overflow hidden could work.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the syntax...

```
background: #8DC63F url("images/footer.png") repeat-x bottom center;
```

and

```
padding: 10px 0 0 0;
```

I would also remove the non-breaking space paragraph, there's no point to it. If you want more space at the bottom, add padding to the div. Don't use empty paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last `<p class="footer-text">&nbsp;</p>` to remove the gap.

Comment: <p class="footer-text">&nbsp;</p> I removed. But my issue is gap between browser window and the footer, hope u can make out the gap , see the FF bar having firebug extension, u can probably see the gap

Comment: is there any other div which is containing this div? that might have some padding or margin. Also, check if body had some padding or margin.

Comment: See this JSfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/89U6b/ I don't see any gap between the footer and window.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use a separate `div` or `br` to clear the floating. That might solve your problem too. Otherwise remove any padding inside the footer to see if this is causing problems.

HTML

```
   <div class="clr"></div>
   <div id="footer">
      <p class="footer-text">Home | Services | About Us | Products | Contact Us</p> 
      <p class="footer-text">2011 &copy; All Rights Reserved.</p>
      <p class="footer-text">&nbsp;</p>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .clr {
         clear:both;
     }
```